# For $t\in(0,1/2),p_t(x)=(t-t^2)x^2-(1-t)x+t^2$ has the roots $\alpha_t,\beta_t$

Tags: real-analysis

For $t\in(0,1/2),p_t(x)=(t-t^2)x^2-(1-t)x+t^2$ has the roots $\alpha_t,\beta_t$ then Could anyone tell me which of the following is true?

$A)\alpha_t,\beta_t\in\mathbb{C}$

$B)$ For infinitely many values of $t$ the corresponding root $\alpha_t$ is rational and $\beta_t$ is irrational.

$C)$ $\alpha_t,\beta_t$ are real and positive ,and one of them is $>1$ and another is $<1$

$D)\lim_{t\uparrow {1\over 2}}\Rightarrow|a_t-\beta_t|\to 0$

here is my thought

let for some $t\in(0,1/2),\alpha_t,\beta_t$ be real roots

then by Roles Theorem $p'_t(x)=0$ for some $c\in (\alpha_t,\beta_t)$

but  $p'_t(x)\ne 0$ so $A$ is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $t \not \in \{0,1\}$ we may divide $p_t(x)$ by $t-t^2$.  At a root, $x$, this gives \begin{align*}0 &= \frac{p_t(x)}{t-t^2} \\ &= x^2 - \frac{1}{t}x + \frac{t}{1-t} \\ 
&= x^2 - \left(\alpha_t + \beta_t\right)x + \alpha_t \beta_t \\
&= \left(x-\alpha_t\right)\left(x-\beta_t\right) \end{align*}  Then we read off the matching coefficients: $\alpha_t + \beta_t = \frac{1}{t}$ and $\alpha_t \beta_t = \frac{t}{1-t}$.

The first is true, but over general.  You should have no trouble showing the discriminant of the polynomial is positive for $t \in (0,1)$.  The roots are actually in $\mathbb{R}$.

If $t$ is rational, then $\alpha_t$ and  $\beta_t$ are either both rational or both irrational (otherwise their product and sum can't simultaneously be rational).  If $\alpha_t$ is rational and $\beta_t$ is irrational, the linear coefficient gives that $t$ is irrational, but the converse isn't automatic, so good luck.  (Try eliminating $\alpha_t$ between the two coefficient equations.  If you're lucky, you'll get something that simplifies enough that $\beta_t$ irrational forces $t$ irrational, but I'm not convinced this works.)

You should have no trouble showing $\frac{t}{t-1} \in (0,1)$ for $t \in (0,1/2)$ so the roots have the same sign.  If their product is small, in $(0,1)$, but their sum is big ($\frac{1}{t} \in (2,\infty)$) one is big and one is very small.

In the form above, the limit as $t\rightarrow 1/2$ is trivial to find.  It's $x^2-2x+1$ which is easy to factor.

Comment: roots are actually in $\mathbb{R}$?